# Output of a process displayed in multiple consoles

Tags: python, linux, ssh, console

I have a python script that runs continuously in background and print some logs on standard output.
If I log with the same user on the same machine via ssh however I cannot see the output since (I guess) I opened a different shell.
Is there any way to specify that the standard output of this process must be seen by all the shell where I am logged with the same username of the one who launched the process?

Alternatively I thought of redirecting the output to a file and open this file… however I would prefer avoiding such a solution.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion…

Comment: This is what `screen` is for...

Comment: I often do in that case redirect the output to a file, and run `tail -f` in a separate terminal.

Comment: Use syslog- thats what its for.  Use a local facility and the `syslog` module in python.  Whenever you login, you have a single file to look at or you could send those logs to a collector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that indeed screen does what i need... 
Thanks Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX you could write to all shells using the command `wall`. I'm not sure if there is a Python binding for `wall` though.